# Show the download progress by default and no hide button

Tags: inno-setup, inno-download-plugin

When starting to download files from my setup, it only appears **total progress** and the button **details** to show what appears in the next image:

[image]

What I want to do is to have that step by default without hitting details button and not showing the hide button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume, that we are talking about this [`Inno Download Plugin`](http://mitrich.net23.net/?/inno-download-plugin.html). On its [`source code page`](https://code.google.com/p/inno-download-plugin/source/browse/) I found the [`idp.iss`](https://code.google.com/p/inno-download-plugin/source/browse/idp.iss) script file which seems to be an interface to the library. It contains the [`idpShowDetails`](https://code.google.com/p/inno-download-plugin/source/browse/idp.iss#115) function which if you call with the `show` parameter set to True will show the detail components, that you can see by clicking the details button. What remains then is hiding that details button, which in the script is accessible through the [`IDPForm`](https://code.google.com/p/inno-download-plugin/source/browse/idp.iss#82) record variable's [`DetailsButton`](https://code.google.com/p/inno-download-plugin/source/browse/idp.iss#72) member. Through this member you can set the `Visible` property to False to hide that button.

To realize this without modifying the original scripts you can include the following piece of code into your existing script:

```
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  // if the downloader page was just shown, then...
  if CurPageID = IDPForm.Page.ID then
  begin
    // show the detail components
    idpShowDetails(True);
    // and hide the details button
    IDPForm.DetailsButton.Visible := False;
  end;
end;
```

And a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I test it in the afternoon and I commented, thank you

Comment: Please note that the online help is no longer available for this tool.